# How to convert several lists to a list of dicts in python?

Tags: python

I have a program that takes 2 numbers and subtracts them and also tells us if the individual places i.e. ones, tens and hundreds are smaller than the number they are being subtracted from and if they need to borrow.

```
a=2345
b=1266
o=[int(d) for d in str(a)]
a=[int(d) for d in str(a)]
b=[int(d) for d in str(b)]
x=len(a)
y=len(b)
i=1
state=[]
c=[]
for n in range(x):
    if a[x-i]<b[y-i]:
        a[x-i]+=10
        a[x-i-1]-=1
        state.append(True)
    else:
        state.append(False)
    i+=1
i=1    
for m in range(x):
    c.append(a[x-i]-b[y-i])
    i+=1
c=c[::-1]
print(o) #before borrow
print(a) #after borrow
print(b) #number to subtract
print(c) #result
print(state) #if borrowed
```

And this is my output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 2, 13, 15]
[1, 2, 6, 6]
[1, 0, 7, 9]
[False, False, False, False]
```

Here is my question:
1) I want to map the results to a list of dictionary for each place like below:

```
[{'initial_num': '5', 'after_borrow': '15', 'state': True, 'after_subtract': '9'},
{'initial_num': '4', 'after_borrow': '13', 'state': True, 'after_subtract': '7'}...]
```

How do I do this so that I have 4 dicts in the list each corresponding to a particular position?

Comment: What is your python's version? My `state` is `[True, True, False, False]`, which is different from yours. This is strange. I use python 3.7.3.

Comment: I restarted the kernel and got the correct output. Weird. Ill edit the question and remove the first part. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your code shows that you already know how to append objects to a list. Do you know how to create a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists you are interested in to `dict`s with list comprehension

```
l = [{'initial_num': x, 'after_borrow': y, 'state': z, 'after_subtract': k} for x, y, z, k in zip(o, a, state, c)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can achieve what you want.

```
a=2345
b=1266
o=[int(d) for d in str(a)]
a=[int(d) for d in str(a)]
b=[int(d) for d in str(b)]
x = len(a)
y = len(b)
i=1
state=[]
c=[]
for n in range(x):
    if a[x-i] < b[y-i]:
        a[x-i] += 10
        a[x-i-1] -= 1
        state.append(True)
    else:
        state.append(False)
    i+=1
i=1    
for m in range(x):
    c.append(a[x-i]-b[y-i])
    i += 1
c=c[::-1]
print(o) #before borrow
print(a) #after borrow
print(b) #number to subtract
print(c) #result
print(state) #if borrowed

result = []
for i in range(len(o)):
    idx = len(o) - i - 1
    result.append({
        'initial_num': o[idx],
        'after_borrow': a[idx],
        'state': state[idx],
        'after_subtract': c[idx]
    })
print(result)
```